# RecyclerView "will show item at position" listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

What is the `RecyclerView` equivalent of Swift `UICollectionView`'s `willDisplayCellAtIndexPath` and `didEndDisplayingCellAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

The recyclerview's adapter class uses `onBindViewHolder` and in there you can catch the creation of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what swift methods do but Adapters `onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder)` and `onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder)` give you the most precise moment for when an item is being displayed and when it leaves the view.

You will need to use provided `ViewHolder`s `getAdapterPosition()` to resolve the items position in the list then.